coinpayments api ipn callback response issue - status not updating database record
Hello everyone i am trying to integrate coinpayments api using php. but the issue is the callback webhook code is not getting any response from the api. if anyone can help me to fix this i am very happy with that. because i am struggling about this matter since 3 years. and i am always trying to do new things.
orders are successfully creating. but i don't know the api is sending ipn callback response to webhook.php or not. because i am trying to update my database table record. based on the status response.
also i was tried Public_key and Private_key too. and i was tried.



//Here is the webhook.php code to get response from the coinpayments.


<?php    
    // Fill these in with the information from your CoinPayments.net account.
    $cp_merchant_id = '12345'; //dummy marchan_id 
    $cp_ipn_secret = '12345'; //dummy secret key
    $cp_debug_email = 'myemail@mail.com';

    //These would normally be loaded from your database, the most common way is to pass the Order ID through the 'custom' POST field.
    $order_currency = 'USD';
    $order_total = 10.00;

    function errorAndDie($error_msg) {
        global $cp_debug_email;
        if (!empty($cp_debug_email)) {
            $report = 'Error: '.$error_msg."\n\n";
            $report .= "POST Data\n\n";
            foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
                $report .= "|$k| = |$v|\n";
            }
            mail($cp_debug_email, 'CoinPayments IPN Error', $report);
        }
        die('IPN Error: '.$error_msg);
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['ipn_mode']) || $_POST['ipn_mode'] != 'hmac') {
        errorAndDie('IPN Mode is not HMAC');
    }

    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC'])) {
        errorAndDie('No HMAC signature sent.');
    }

    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if ($request === FALSE || empty($request)) {
        errorAndDie('Error reading POST data');
    }

   // if (!isset($_POST['merchant']) || $_POST['merchant'] != trim($cp_merchant_id)) {
    //    errorAndDie('No or incorrect Merchant ID passed');
   // }

    $hmac = hash_hmac("sha512", $request, trim($cp_ipn_secret));
    if (!hash_equals($hmac, $_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC'])) {
    //if ($hmac != $_SERVER['HTTP_HMAC']) { <-- Use this if you are running a version of PHP below 5.6.0 without the hash_equals function
        errorAndDie('HMAC signature does not match');
    }

    // HMAC Signature verified at this point, load some variables.

    $ipn_type = $_POST['ipn_type'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $amount1 = floatval($_POST['amount1']);
    $amount2 = floatval($_POST['amount2']);
    $currency1 = $_POST['currency1'];
    $currency2 = $_POST['currency2'];
    $status = intval($_POST['status']);
    $status_text = $_POST['status_text'];

   // if ($ipn_type != 'button') { // Advanced Button payment
    //    die("IPN OK: Not a button payment");
    //}
    
    $new_status = '';
            if ($status >= 100) {
                $new_status = 'Completed'; // Payment completed successfully
                } elseif ($status == 0) {
                $new_status = 'Pending'; // Pending Payment
                } elseif ($status == 2) {
                $new_status = 'Processing'; // Queued for nightly payout, waiting for Confirmations
                } elseif ($status == -1) {
                $new_status = 'Cancelled'; // Cancelled / Timeout
                } elseif ($status == 1) {
                $new_status = 'Confirmed'; // We have confirmed coin reception from the buyer
                } else {
                $new_status = 'Pending'; // Default status for other pending cases
            }
    
    //depending on the API of your system, you may want to check and see if the transaction ID $txn_id has already been handled before at this point

    // Check the original currency to make sure the buyer didn't change it.
    //if ($currency1 != $order_currency) {
    //    errorAndDie('Original currency mismatch!');
    //}

    // Check amount against order total
    //if ($amount1 < $order_total) {
     //   errorAndDie('Amount is less than order total!');
    //}
 
   // Example: Update deposit status for the user in your database
            include_once('../dbconnection.php');
            
            
            if ($currency1 == 'USDT' || $currency1 == 'USDT.TRC20') {
                $conversion_rate = amount1 * 83.69;
                } elseif ($currency1 == 'TRX') {
                $conversion_rate = amount1 * 9.27;
                } else {
                // Handle other currencies or invalid currency1 types here
                // You can set a default conversion rate or display an error message
                $new_status = 'rejected';
            }
            
            $new_amount =  $conversion_rate;
            $gateway_id = $txn_id;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM deposits_table WHERE gateway_id = '$gateway_id'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // If the gateway_id exists in the table, update specific columns
                $update_sql = "UPDATE deposits_table SET 
                               converted_amount = '$new_amount',
                               status = '$new_status',
                               transaction_hash = '$gateway_id'
                               WHERE gateway_id = '$gateway_id'";

                if ($conn->query($update_sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Record updated successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                }
            } else {
                echo "No records found for the specified gateway_id";
            }

            // Close the database connection
            $conn->close();
            //================END UPDATE===================================
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   die('IPN OK');
   
   ?>


"but i don't know the api is sending ipn callback response to webhook.php or not." - then go check the web server's access log and find out.
